# Can't play video file to virtual camera and then webcam to virtual camera v4l2

Tags: ffmpeg, debian, v4l2

When I try to play a video to a virtual camera it works
but when I try to play webcam to virtual camera it doesn't do anything.

What I do:

Playing video to virtual camera:

`ffmpeg -re -i "yt.mkv"   -map 0:v -f v4l2 "/dev/video2"`
and then ^C

Playing webcam to virtual camera:

`ffmpeg -i "/dev/video0"  -map 0:v -f v4l2 "/dev/video2"`

What happens when I do last command:
nothing. The last frame of the played video just stays there, frozen.

when i use `ffplay /dev/video2` it outputs this:

`[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x7fdcf4000b80] Dequeued v4l2 buffer contains 460800 bytes, but 1382400 were expected. Flags: 0x00000001.`

i can play 2 different videos so i dont know why it isn't working

How do I get it to work?

edit: logs

first command

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'yt.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:43.28, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 2025 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:43.281000000
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      DURATION        : 00:00:43.234000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, video4linux2,v4l2, to '/dev/video2':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 663552 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      DURATION        : 00:00:43.234000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 rawvideo
frame=   27 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.45 bitrate=N/A speed=0.887x
```

second one :

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 13203.980211, bitrate: 110592 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x360, 110592 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, video4linux2,v4l2, to '/dev/video2':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 640x360, q=2-31, 82944 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 rawvideo
frame=  222 fps= 32 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:07.40 bitrate=N/A dup=117 drop=0 speed=1.06x
```

ffplay-

```
ffplay version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2003-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video2':B sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Duration: N/A, start: 893.874176, bitrate: 82944 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 640x360, 82944 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x7f5f30000b80] Dequeued v4l2 buffer contains 348160 bytes, but 345600 were expected. Flags: 0x00000001.
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x7f5f30000b80] Dequeued v4l2 buffer contains 348160 bytes, but 345600 were expected. Flags: 0x00000001.
```

Comment: Show the complete logs from `ffmpeg -i "/dev/video0"  -map 0:v -f v4l2 "/dev/video2" ` and `ffplay /dev/video2`.

Comment: @llogan how do i do that? any specific command?

Comment: I meant the "console output" that ffmpeg shows when you run it. You can just copy and paste that. "Log" isn't really the correct term, but users seem to understand it better.

Comment: @llogan ive added the ffmpeg console output

Comment: You omitted the `ffplay` output. (Didn't need the output from the `-i yt.mkv` command.) Anyway, without it I don't have an answer. I can only recommend to upgrade your ffmpeg before doing anything else (try a version from git master), either [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). Then try a few command variants: `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -c copy -f v4l2 /dev/video2` or `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -f v4l2 -vf format=yuv420p /dev/video2`. Might not be a ffmpeg problem. Might be v4l2 problem.

Comment: i added it now. maybe i should go do like a bug report or something on ffmpeg website

Comment: You will be asked to try a build from the git master branch if you submit a bug report using any release version. So try downloading or compiling it as mentioned in my previous comment before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

Comment: It doesnt work. im testing with a website that accesses the webcam but when i try to `ffplay /dev/video2` error apears :  `[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x7fd768000b80] Dequeued v4l2 buffer contains 460800 bytes, but 1382400 were expected. Flags: 0x00000001.
`