How to stream a local video to virtual webcam using ffmpeg?
I have a mp4 video file named trial_video.mp4. I want it to stream to virtual camera and virtual microphone(both are installed already) using ffmpeg on windows 11.
I have searched on internet a lot but could not find anything related.
Help me building command for this purpose.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There are LOADS of questions on this site about virtual webcams, and at least a few of these are specifically about using FFMPEG to stream the video. Here's one I found: https://superuser.com/questions/1623575/cant-play-video-file-to-virtual-camera-and-then-webcam-to-virtual-camera-v4l2

The link you provided is only valid linux.
